# Parsing XML when the parent and child tags are the same in JAVA

Tags: java, xml

Quick Question. I have XML similiar to below.

```
        <dst_adtr>
           <dst_adtr>
              <Name>TEST Name</Name>
              <Table>objects</Table>
           </dst_adtr>
        </dst_adtr>
        <dst_adtr>
           <dst_adtr>
              <Name>TEST Name TWO</Name>
              <Table>objects</Table>
           </dst_adtr>
        </dst_adtr>
```

As you can see the parent tag and the child tag are the same.
I want to be able to search and then extract the information in the `<Name>` tag. How would I be able to specifically get to the Name tag?

Answer (score 0):

If your schema is always going to contain above format, then you can use SAX Parser and every time you encounter a new dst_adtr node create a new POJO and grab the name and table body information. If you don't want to parse the content manually then use JAXB. Create an xsd file and auto generate the POJO's and post that you just have to invoke unmarshall to extract data from the xml

Answer (score 0):

An example using a Pull parser and no external dependencies:

```
public void pullParse(InputStream in)
        throws FactoryConfigurationError, XMLStreamException {
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.TRUE);
    XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(in);

    boolean inName = false;
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent o = reader.nextEvent();
        if (inName && o.isCharacters()) {
            System.out.println("name: " + o.asCharacters().getData());
        } else if (inName && o.isEndElement()
                && "Name".equals(o.asEndElement().getName().toString())) {
            inName = false;
        }
        if (o.isStartElement()
                && "Name".equals(o.asStartElement().getName().toString())) {
            inName = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One option is you could just read the xml as a String and use a regex for matching.

```
(?:<Name>(.*?)</Name>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Q4DLWNqVeiZoqS-u)

Then you can just extract all the matches.